# Dynamic arguments using maven appassembler plugin with JSW platform

Tags: maven, appassembler, yajsw

I have a program that accept 3 or 4 arugments and i'm trying to execute the main class with these parameters using the generated daemon. I just see in docs that it is necessary to configure the parameters previously through wrapper.conf defining wrapper.app.parameter..

I'm need a way that i can start a program like this:

./program start parameter1 parameter2 parameter3

Someone know how to do that?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your full pom file and what exactly does not work? Apart from that a daemon should have only a single argument `start`, `stop` etc. If you like having supplemental parameters you should use loading  of a configuration file. An other option might be to generate several daemons which have a different configuration to support different scenarios.

Comment: Yes, i read the docs. The problem is that parameters are not fixes. Several daemons will not work. I think i will use a single program configuration.